# Nodejs is not receiving JSON.string, not even the ping

Tags: json, node.js

I have an angular2 service that calls the http object and makes a request to my nodejs server.

Most of the communications with the server work except for a string that contains an array, for some odd reason. **All the requests are JSON.stringified before leaving the frontend with application/json headers.**

This one is received in the server and works: `{key: some_info_object}`

**Console log in nodejs:**`Body received in nodejs, body: {key: some_info_object}`

---

**This one**, however, **does not work**. Nodejs does not even announce the pin: `{key: [some_object,some_object,some_object]}`. **Normally this post parameter seems to be bulky (around 800 chars or more, I don't know if that is relevant).**

It seems to me like nodejs does not read or even receive post data that is basically objects inside an array, even if stringified.

Is there any reason this might be happening?

Probably relevant code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

So, any idea?
Let me know please

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post code and actual inputs, if the inputs are too long just post a smaller sample that does not work for you, this question has too little info.